# error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

my react native version is "react-native": "0.59.10",

Xcode version 13.3

when i try to run. ==>. npx react-native run-ios

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.